# Providing a link between gazebo plugins and base_link in the robot model

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I have added the following plugins to my .gazebo file. When I do **rostopic echo** for all the topics, all the information about poses are updated. My problem is that when I do "rosrun tf view_frames", there is no link between odom and base_link. I would like to update the information of what I got from Gazebo into rviz tf tree. So, do I need to add some tags to the plugins in .gazebo file? Or do I need to add some links in the urdf file?

```
<gazebo> <!-- GPS plugin -->
<plugin name="robot_gps_sim" filename="libhector_gazebo_ros_gps.so">
  <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
  <updateRate>4.0</updateRate>
  <bodyName>base_link</bodyName>
  <topicName>gps</topicName>
  <velocityTopicName>gps_velocity</velocityTopicName>
  <drift>5.0 5.0 5.0</drift>
  <gaussianNoise>0.1 0.1 0.1</gaussianNoise>
  <velocityDrift>0 0 0</velocityDrift>
  <velocityGaussianNoise>0.1 0.1 0.1</velocityGaussianNoise>
</plugin>

<!-- Groundtruth plugin -->
<plugin name="robot_groundtruth_sim" filename="libgazebo_ros_p3d.so">
  <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
  <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
  <bodyName>base_link</bodyName>
  <topicName>odom</topicName>
  <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>
  <frameName>map</frameName>
  <xyzOffsets>0 0 0</xyzOffsets>
  <rpyOffsets>0 0 0</rpyOffsets>
</plugin> 

<!-- IMU plugin -->
<plugin name="robot_imu_sim" filename="libhector_gazebo_ros_imu.so">
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>100.0</updateRate> 
    <bodyName>base_link</bodyName>
    <frameID>robot_link1</frameID>
    <topicName>robot/IMU</topicName>
    <xyzOffset>0.0 0.0 0.0</xyzOffset>
    <rpyOffset>0.0 0.0 0.0</rpyOffset>
    <gaussianNoise>0</gaussianNoise>
    <accelDrift>0.5 0.5 0.5</accelDrift>
    <accelGaussianNoise>0.35 0.35 0.3</accelGaussianNoise>
    <rateDrift>0.0 0.0 0.0</rateDrift>
    <rateGaussianNoise>0.00 0.00 0.00</rateGaussianNoise>
    <headingDrift>0.0</headingDrift>
    <headingGaussianNoise>0.00</headingGaussianNoise>
</plugin> </gazebo>
```

Actually, I asked [another question](http://answers.ros.org/question/234040/tf-tree-problem-with-map-odom-base_link/) in answers.ros.org, but I am not sure whether the problem has to do with the the way I have defined the plugins for gazebo.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13260/providing-a-link-between-gazebo-plugins-and-base_link-in-the-robot-model/) by [MahsaP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1291/mahsap/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am using the gazebo_ros diff drive plugin and there is the following code which publish a transform between the world and the vehicle.

```
transform_broadcaster_->sendTransform (
            tf::StampedTransform ( base_footprint_to_odom, current_time,
                               odom_frame, base_footprint_frame ) );
```

My odometry frame is "world" and the robotBaseFrame is "vehicle" (which correspond to the base link of my robot).

---

Originally posted by [Brosseau.F](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2389/brosseau.f/) with karma: 284 on 2016-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0